# problem linking pcl_io

Tags: ros, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm building this on my Raspberry Pi - anyone any idea what might be wrong re: the extract error message:
Both libtheoradec.so.1, and libspeex.so.1, are on the system.

Thanks in advance

Mark

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtheoradec.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linuxgnueabihf
/libavcodec.so.53, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libspeex.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabih /libavcodec.so.53, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so.53: undefined reference to `speex_uwb_mode'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so.53: undefined reference to `speex_encoder_init'
```

/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so.53: undefined reference to `speex_encode_int'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64857/problem-linking-pcl_io/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you consider setting the linker flags via cmake as suggested by the error message, e. g. :

```
  set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -rpath -rpath-link" )
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0